# Fuel php orm profile like

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp, social-media-like

First really sorry if its a stupid question but I'm a beginner.

So I recently started working with fulephp and I have a small site, and would like to give the users the ability to like other users profile.

But I'm a bit unexperienced at this part. So I have a table `users_like`

```
id | users_id | liked_by
1  | 5        | 1
2  | 5        | 3
3  | 1        | 2
4  | 1        | 9
```

the `user_id` is who got the like and the `liked_by` is who gave the like

So I have a like button on the users profile

```
<button class="like btn btn-primary" data-like="<?php echo $user->profile['user_id']; ?>">Like</button>
```

the `data-like` contains the users id who gets the like

And the insert looks like this

PHP function

```
public function action_like($id)
    {
        if(Input::is_ajax()):

            $response = Response::forge();

                $like = Model_Like::forge();
                $like->user_id = $id;
                $like->liked_by = Session::get('sentry_user');
                $like->save();

                $response->body(json_encode(array(
                    'status' => 'liked',
                )));

            return $response;


        endif;// is ajax
    }
```

jQuery ajax posts

```
$('button.like').on('click', function(){
    var likeId = $(this).data('like');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: siteUrl + "profile/like/" + likeId,
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },

        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.status === "liked") {
                $(this).removeClass('like')
                .addClass('unlike')
                .text('Un-Like');

            }
        }, 

        complete: function()
        {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

So actually my logic was this.

The orm retuns the users likes, and I was thinking to do this

```
if(Session::get('sentry_user') != $like['liked_by']) {
  <button class="like btn btn-primary" data-like="<?php echo $user->profile['user_id']; ?>">Like</button>
}
else {
  <button class="unlike btn btn-primary" data-like="<?php echo $user->profile['user_id']; ?>">Un-Like</button>

}
```

So if the logged in users id is not equals to the `liked_by` than show the button Like otherwise show the button unlike, and if they click that a function will remove the like

But I was silly because I forgot that this actually returns arrays so this is a no-no

So my question is that, I should use jquery cookie somehow to achive the following.

When an user clicks on Like some how get the user has liked that profile and change the button to unlike.

Or could please someone give me a little hint for this solution, just a hint or advice.

Comment: Can't understand ur question fully. The problem is that button like and unlike does not working as expected?

Comment: the problem is that im not able to think out a logic, what would create the following: if user likes change the button to unlike and keep i, sorry if my question wasnt clear

Comment: khhmm, i'm don't vote u down, and i can't vote down anyway(need 125 rating)

Answer (score -1):

In my point of view i do this task such:

1)user login and we save it id to session data

2)when user request some page we return button "like" or "unlike" (recommend to output 2 buttons one hidden, see below)

3)when user clicks "like": do post by jquery like and after success u mush change to button to unlike it can be done by changing style, text, events, etc, but i would u recommend to hide "like" button and show "unlike"

4)when user clicks "unlike": same as 3) but change to "like" button on success

PS: at server side i recommend to return to true or false, on success or fail.

Comment: thats nice thank you but, how can i keep the status? i mean when an user likes keep the unlike state? for example after page refresh

Comment: u save data about like's in table users_like, get it from there and do output when user refresh page.